# JqGrid not saving data to database

Tags: php, sql, json, jqgrid

i am trying to create an editable grid with jqgrid - however I cant get the data to save to the database – I know its probably something really simple, but coding is not really my thing – just trying to help out a friend. Here is my latest html. I seem to be going round in circles when i google…

many thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DT…..strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8″ />
<title>xxxxxx</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="timesheet_login.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="oneline_logo.gif">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 75%;
}
</style>

<script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/js/jqModal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/js/jqDnR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ 
  $("#rota").jqGrid({
    url:'example.php',
    datatype: "json",
 mtype: 'POST',
    colNames:['Date', 'HPJ', 'Recycler','CCTV','Assistant'],
    colModel:[
     {name:'date',index:'date', width:90,editable:true},
     {name:'hpj',index:'hpj', width:100,editable:true},
      {name:'recycler',index:'recycler', width:100,editable:true},
      {name:'cctv',index:'cctv', width:100,editable:true},
   {name:'assistant',index:'assistant', width:100,editable:true}
    ],
 rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pcelltbl',
    sortname: 'date',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"Cell Edit Example",
 forceFit : true,
 cellEdit: true,
 cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
 editurl:'example.php?action=save'
});

jQuery("#rota").jqGrid('navGrid','#pgwidth',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
});
</script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="topcontent">
 <br><br>
</div><!– end topcontainer –>

<div id="centercontent">

<table id="rota"><tr><td/></tr></table> 
<div id="pager"></div>

<script src="celledit.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

</div>

<div id="footercontent">
</div><!– end footercontent –>

</body>
</html>
```

example.php:

```
<?php 
$dbhost = xxxxx.com';  $dbuser = 'xxx';  $dbpassword = 'xxx';  $dbdatabase = xxxx;

$page = $_REQUEST['page'];  // get the requested page
$limit = $_REQUEST['rows']; // get how many rows we want to have into the grid
$sidx = $_REQUEST['sidx']; // get index row - i.e. user click to sort
$sord = $_REQUEST['sord']; // get the direction
if(!$sidx) $sidx =1;

// connect to the database
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbdatabase) or die("Error conecting to db.");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM rota"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC); 
$count = $row['count']; 


if( $count >0 ) {
    $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
} else {
    $total_pages = 0;
}
if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;
$start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1)
if($start <0) $start = 0; 


$SQL = "SELECT date, hpj, recycler, cctv, assistant FROM rota ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit";
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn t execute query.".mysql_error());

$responce->page = $page;
$responce->total = $total_pages;
$responce->records = $count;
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $responce->rows[] = array('id'=>$row['date'], "cell"=>array($row['date'], $row['hpj'], $row['recycler'], $row['cctv'], $row['assistant']));



}        
echo json_encode($responce);

?>
```

Comment: Do you have any code on the webserver that is supposed to save the data in the database? e.g the code for example.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#properties) of the cell editing. You should use `cellsubmit: 'remote'` and `cellurl` instead of `cellsubmit: 'clientArray'`. You need of course write on the server part (referenced by `cellurl` URL) the code which save the changes in the database. The option `editurl` defines the URL used for inline and form editing but not for cell editing.

Comment: I am now using editurl - waht needs to be in the php file to allow the data to be saved to database?

Comment: @user1150262: You should read [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#properties). The documentation of the `cellsubmit` describes the format of the data sent. You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to examine the data which sill be send in the HTTP request to the server. I can't give you more tips about the PHP implementation because I don't use PHP myself.